# Display currency field on vf email template as it appears on standard page

Tags: visualforce, email, email-template, multi-currency

[image]

I am creating a visualforce email template where i want to display the currency field as shown above. Is it possible?

Comment: Create one formula field and accumulate the currency field in that formula.use the formula field in your vf email template.